# How Browser optimizing my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, browser

Is JavaScript interpreted to bytecode with optimization in browsers, or just simply executes from script lines?

For example I am having two methods:

```
// function with clear defining local variables for each calculation
function moreReadable(p1, p2, p3) {
   var a = p1 + p2;
   var resA = someFunction(a);
      // some actions with resA 
   var b = p2 + p3;
   var resB = someFunction(b);
      // some actions with resB
   var c = p1 + p3;
   var resC = someFunction(c);
      // some actions with resA
}

// function which reuses first declared variable, for all calculations
function optimized(p1, p2, p3){
   var a = p1 + p2;
   a = someFunction(a);
      // some actions with a
   a = p2 + p3;
   a = someFunction(a);
      // some actions with a
   a = p1 + p3;
   a = someFunction(a);
      // some actions with a
}
```

Will second method give me an advantage in performance or memory usage? It obviously uses less local variables. 
But is there sense of doing optimizations? Will Chrome optimize both to the same executive code?

Comment: *"But is there sense of doing optimizations?"* – not on this level, no. Even if the browser *didn't* optimize it, you're saving 4 local variables which has a practical effect of nothing at all.

Comment: First rule of optimization: Never do it blindly, **Measure**. Then read a little on a topic before asking SO.

Comment: I was not asking about the sense of first or second method! This is a simple example, so really the only way to find it out is to measure. Thank you for NO ANSWERS. You`ve helped. A lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the following article about V8 Javascript Engine that Chrome is using:

- https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements

There is certainly an optimisation happening from the engine BUT this doesn't means that it optimises your code.

It's quite a big article/wiki but it will help you a lot understanding how JS interprets into bytecode by understanding the engine.

Now regarding your code example, you are just solving readability issues there and you'll not get boost in performance. JS is a very strange language even that is simple. That means that some time less code is better and some times not.

It all comes at the end in your code complexity and architecture.

Still though depending your codebase/project you should measure the performance and tweak it to get better results ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AndriiBogachenko Did you checked it? Is my answer good for you then to accept it?

Comment: I`ve checked and that is realy a good explanation. How the things works, at least in the V8.

Comment: Good to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to give absolutelly determinated answer for the question. 
First of all, optimization of variable declaration depends on **JS-engine implementation**.

For example, Chrome's V8 - compiles JS to the machine code, using [two different compilers](http://jayconrod.com/posts/51/a-tour-of-v8-full-compiler): quick and optimized.

JS function is compiled with **optimized** compiler, when V8 understands that the function uses rather often, and there is a reason to spend more time on compilation to gain time on function usage. In that case there`s definetly no difference between *moreReadable()* and *optimized()* functions.

Talking about V8's **quick**(base) compiler, I think it compiles not absoultely blindly, so the comparing function might also result same machine code. To make it sure it`s required to compile both functions and compare resulted machine code. But that is not a 5 minutes task.